# MVC: Plugging a C++ Model into a Web-based View

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, c++

**Background**

I am writing a tool using MVC where the model is written in C++, controller in JavaScript/jQuery and the view in HTML/CSS. The reason the model is in C++ is for eventual portability to a thick client from the "speed build" on web.

**Issue**

My major roadblock at this point is connecting my C++ model to the HTML form that is currently collecting input data from the user.

I have looked into [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten) for compiling the C++ directly into JavaScript, but I don't like the idea of having my underlying model be visible to the end user in *any form*. This is due to the model being hooked up to a MySQL server handling a lot of sensitive data. I want to minimize risk of the end user accidentally (or purposely) messing with the function call invoking the model.

I have done quite a bit of research on PHP/C++ linking, but all the resources I could find have been severely outdated and/or convoluted.

I'd ideally like to have the the data pushed to the server using a POST method before invoking the model so I can have maximum control over input validation both on the end user and server side.

I've also thought about using PHP to push to the MySQL server then having the C++ pull down from the server, but this seems a little obfuscated and raises the issue of when/how to wake the C++ up.

**Question**

Is there a good way to maintain security of my model (have it run entirely server-side behind a POST method) as well as the understandability of how this was implemented? I am a temp employee and my project will pass to other hands for the port to a thick client from web.

Speed is also a concern, but I'm assuming (or hoping) that the only bottleneck will be the pipe/script between the POST to the server and the C++ since most of the heavy-lifting will be occurring in the model.

Comment: Have you considered using a C++ HTTP library, e.g., [libmicrohttpd](https://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/)? The idea here is your whole HTTP server would be in C++—no need to cross language boundaries.

Comment: That looks promising, but I'm not sure if I'll be allowed to configure my own HTTP server (this is going to be an internal tool). I'm waiting to hear back from IT, but from the conversations I've had it seems like I will be building on top of a LAMP stack.

Comment: @CraigM.Brandenburg forgot to tag you see above --^

Answer (score 0):

What about not putting any business logic in your model and instead break the model up into an `Entity` and `Service`?

You could then use [emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten) on the `Entity` while your `Service` holds all of your MySql connection logic.

Comment: I did some searching but could not find online resources for this model abstraction. Could you please explain further the distinction between `Entity` and `Service`?

Comment: do a search for "entity vs service"